# Dificulties to display my firebase data in Angular with ordeyByChild

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've a database for my users organized like this :

```
Database
 - Users
  - Id (determined thanks to the push method)
    - email
    - firstName
    - ptsTotal
    - ...
```

I want to use the orderByChild method to establish a ranking of my users according to ptsTotal (which is a number of points in a game).

Below is my component in Angular :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UsersService} from '../../services/users.service';
import {User} from '../../models/user.model';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-total',
  templateUrl: './total.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./total.component.scss']
})
export class TotalComponent implements OnInit {

  usersRanking:User[] = [];

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRanking();
    //1
    console.log(this.usersRanking);
  }

  getRanking(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users').orderByChild('ptsTotal')
    .on('child_added',(data)=>{
          this.usersRanking = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
          //2
          console.log(this.usersRanking);
      });
  }
}
```

1st Weird thing. The results has not the same shape than when I ask my userlist (without orderByChild). The return result is separate in 4 (because I have 4 users) were as with the userlist I have just 1 object with all my users.

This is the function to get my userlist. I use a users:User[] and emitUsers() is to do an Observable with rxjs.

```
  getUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users')
    .on('value',(data)=>{
      this.users = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
      this.emitUsers();
    });
  }
```

2nd Weird thing. My second console.log() display the 4 results were as the 1st console.log()(The one in the ngOnInit display only one result (My user with the most points).

[image]

3rd Weird thing. My Html is not working. I use a ngFor and the result on my page is 6 lines (And I just have 4 users). This Html is working when I use the same method to just display my users (without order)

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

(Html code below)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2>Users Ranking</h2>
    <div class="list-group"
        *ngFor="let user of usersRanking | keyvalue async">
        <p>firstName : {{user.value.firstName}} - LastName : {{user.value.lastName}} - Number of Points : {{user.value.ptsTotal}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post. For your first question here: can you edit your question to show the code for both case you'e describing, so that we can compare them? It'd also be great if you could show the output for both cases, preferably with `console.log` statements so that we don't have to consider the Angular aspects.

Comment: Sorry Frank if I did wrong. For me, these questions are linked and useful to understand my problem. Which is, I don't understand how to deal with my firebase output with an orderByChild method.

Comment: Posting multiple questions in a single post, makes it unlikely that someone can/will answer them all (as evidenced already by the fact that I only asked about your first question) and makes it more likely that your post will be closed as too broad. I'll have a look at your updated code/output for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your first problem is caused by the different in the listener type you use.

First one:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').orderByChild('ptsTotal')
.on('child_added',(data)=>{
      this.usersRanking = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
      console.log(this.usersRanking);
  });
```

You're observing `child_added` here, which means your callback gets called for each individual child node that matches the query (for each child initially, and then also each time a child is added).

Your second listener is:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users')
.on('value',(data)=>{
  this.users = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
  this.emitUsers();
});
```

Here you listen for `value` events, which means your code gets called with one snapshot of all results (once initially, and then each them there is a change).

So it makes sense that the format looks different for each, as you're getting a different level of results. If you want to see the same type of data in the `value` listener, you'd do:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users')
.on('value',(data)=>{
  data.forEach((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  })
});
```

Using `data.forEach()` here is also key to ensuring you see the values in the order in which you requested them. Without that `data.val()` would actually be in an undefined order, as there no defined order for the fields in JSON.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the thing is I don't manage to display the data in my app with the child_added or the data.forEach value. I don't want to change my function to retrieve my users. My main goal is to establish a ranking and I just want to be able to retrieve and display my data according to ptsTotal.  That's why I explained my full problem and I let the 3 weird things together because they are linked. May be my mistake is at the 1rst weird thing, may be at the 2nd, or the 3rd who knows :) (People probably knows but not me haha)